# MS Word mail merge: MERGESEQ and MOD

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, fieldcodes

Field codes:
[image]

Data:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image]

I was thinking about where I should tweak the codes to fix the issue that the first column of each has three records as other columns do.

Also, a new class name (i.e. 1A, 1B) should be added to the second sheets (i.e. the second and fourth pages).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something more like this:

[image: (page 1 fields)]

[image: (page 2 fields)]

There were two problems - a change of class causes a page break, so at that point you can't rely on on the `{ =mod({ MERGESEQ },3) } = 0` to show you the right place to break next. Because a column break can also cause a page break, you also have to keep count of the columns to ensure that you can insert the class name every time you have a new page.

An advantage of doing it this way is that you can easily change the number of columns and rows per page.

(I have put one other thing in there, because strictly speaking you need to initialize Class1 when you start the merge).